# Glide: What should DataFetcher<InputStream> loadData return?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm new to Glide and am having troubles with my own `ModelLoader` implementation.

I took the [OkHttp Glide integration classes](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/integration/okhttp3/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/integration/okhttp3) as base.

In my GlideModule, I call:

`registry.append(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class,
                new TauaOkHttpLoader.Factory(applicationComponent.tauaOkHttpClient()));`

where `applicationComponent.tauaOkHttpClient()` returns a valid `OkHttpClient` with the necessary headers (I checked it).

Then, in my `HttpLoader`, I have pretty much the same implementation as the class provided in the link above. I created it to use my `OkHttpStreamFetcher`, where I get the result this way:

```
Request.Builder requestBuilder = new 
Request.Builder().url(url.toStringUrl());
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> headerEntry : url.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
        String key = headerEntry.getKey();
        requestBuilder.addHeader(key, headerEntry.getValue());
    }
    Request request = requestBuilder.build();

    call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            callback.onLoadFailed(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            responseBody = response.body();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String encodedImage = responseBody.string();
                long contentLength = encodedImage.length();
                ByteArrayInputStream inputStream =
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT));
                stream = ContentLengthInputStream.obtain(inputStream, contentLength);
                callback.onDataReady(inputStream);
            } else {
                callback.onLoadFailed(new HttpException(response.message(), response.code()));
            }
        }
    });
```

Even though I get a valid encoded string and create the `ByteArrayInputStream` correctly, it still throws an error. I've debuged several times and it gets the correct result. I also tried to change my fetcher to `DataFetcher<byte[]>` and `DataFetcher<Bitmap>` and append it but my fetcher won't even get called. Here's the logcat:

[image: Glide Stack Trace]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was passing in the `contentLength` incorrectly. After assigning it to the length of the array returned by `Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT)`, it worked!